# Dart get date of next friday

Tags: date, dart, countdown

Im trying to make an app that counts down the time untill the next friday, but therefore I need the date of the next friday.
Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us. After you make a good attempt at doing this yourself and if you still have problems, you can update your question with details of the specific problem and what you have tried to solve it, and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we are able to help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Solution

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime next(int day) {
    return this.add(
      Duration(
        days: (day - this.weekday) % DateTime.daysPerWeek,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Testing

```
void main() {
  var today = DateTime.now();
  print(today);
 
  print(today.next(DateTime.friday));
  print(today.next(DateTime.friday).weekday == DateTime.friday);
  
  // Works as expected when the next day is after sunday
  print(today.next(DateTime.monday));
  print(today.next(DateTime.monday).weekday == DateTime.monday);
}
```

#### Output

```
2020-06-24 18:47:40.318
2020-06-26 18:47:40.318
true
2020-06-29 18:47:40.318
true
```

See [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) for more information on `DateTime`.

Comment: Brillant solution. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 7):

**I added some minor adjustments to the code above(answer posted by davideliseo)**

The code above had an issue where it couldn't find the next week's day, but returned the day that was passed into the function.

Example: my DateTime is a Saturday. I Expect the next Saturday in the calendar to be returned NOT the same Saturday that was started with.

Also, I included a previous function because It could be helpful.

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime next(int day) {
    if (day == this.weekday)
      return this.add(Duration(days: 7));
    else {
      return this.add(
        Duration(
          days: (day - this.weekday) % DateTime.daysPerWeek,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  DateTime previous(int day) {
    if (day == this.weekday)
      return this.subtract(Duration(days: 7));
    else {
      return this.subtract(
        Duration(
          days: (this.weekday - day) % DateTime.daysPerWeek,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: here is a concise alternative:       `Duration(days: day == weekday ? 7 : (day - weekday) % DateTime.daysPerWeek),`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a bug with the accepted solution and DST.  Using the workaround shown [here](https://medium.com/pinch-nl/datetime-and-daylight-saving-time-in-dart-9c9468633b5d) I am using:

```
extension MyDateTime on DateTime {
  DateTime next(int day) {
    return DateTime(
      this.year,
      this.month,
      this.day + (day == weekday ? 7 : (day - weekday) % DateTime.daysPerWeek),
    );
  }

  DateTime previous(int day) {
    return DateTime(
      this.year,
      this.month,
      this.day - (day == weekday ? 7 : (weekday - day) % DateTime.daysPerWeek),
    );
  }
}
```