# Dart/Flutter get specific day DateTime of this week

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Using Flutter on Android I am trying to get the specific date of the next Monday, Tuesday and etc. For example, today is 12/9/2020, assuming week starts from Sunday and I need to get the Monday the first date of next Monday will be 13/9/2020.

How I can get this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart get date of next friday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564746/dart-get-date-of-next-friday)

Answer (score 1):

You could check on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62565521/8847585)

He is making a DateTime extension, so you could call the `next` method to find the certain day on the upcoming day